# How to mount hard drives conditionally based upon drive size and type using systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I several linux computers each  has 2 HDD and 1 SSD.

I want to mount with mount points according to certain conditions such as drive size, whether it's an SSD,or from some HD manufacturer.

for example:
1 SSD should be mounted to /home/code
2 HHD should be mounted to /home/data1 
                           /home/data2

I would like to use linux systemd to do so automatically .

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

joseph

Answer (score 0):

You can use UDEV for launch a script on disk connection event.
The bash script test your conditions and mount the device.

Link: [Example to launch a backup script](https://gist.github.com/mqu/8632432)